# Send notification to creator on the basis of post page views in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8

I want to send the notification to the post creator on the basis of page views in laravel. Like when the post gets 1000 views, the creator should get a congratulatory notification. Here the problem is I am using cookies(2 hours) to prevent multiple page views. so the creator gets multiple notifications until views are moved to 1001.

```
if($views == 1000){
        $user = User::find($userid);
        $notificationdetails = [
          'subject' => 'Congratulations, You got your first '.$views. ' views on your new snippet - '.$snippet_title,
          'greeting' => 'Hi, '.$user->name,
          'body' => 'Congratulations, You got your first '.$views. ' views on your new 
     snippet - '.$snippet_title,
          'body1' =>'',
          'thanks' => ' ',
          'actionText' => 'View snippet',
          'actionURL' => url(env('FRONTEND_URL').'/snippets/'.$slug)
                 ];
          Notification::send($user, new BBBnotifications($notificationdetails));

    }
```

Comment: Are you having an issue in sending notifications to the creator, or you are having difficulties in implementing the logic of 2hr limit for each unique view?

Comment: @SarojShrestha Everything is working fine. but I want to send only one notification to the creator. having difficulties in implementing the logic of 2hr limit.

Comment: where are you storing the `views` count? are you storing it in the same post database?

Comment: Yes in the same post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a table in your DB and check if notification sent or read. First you should create a model and related table.

```
if($views == 1000){
        $user = User::find($userid);
        $notification_check = NotificationHistory::where('user_id', $user->id)->where('notification_type', 1000)->first();

        if($notification_check === null)
          {
        $notificationdetails = [
          'subject' => 'Congratulations, You got your first '.$views. ' views on your new snippet - '.$snippet_title,
          'greeting' => 'Hi, '.$user->name,
          'body' => 'Congratulations, You got your first '.$views. ' views on your new 
     snippet - '.$snippet_title,
          'body1' =>'',
          'thanks' => ' ',
          'actionText' => 'View snippet',
          'actionURL' => url(env('FRONTEND_URL').'/snippets/'.$slug),
          'type' => 1000
                 ];
          
          Notification::send($user, new BBBnotifications($notificationdetails));
          NotificationHistory::create([
          'notification_type' => 1000,
          'user_id' => $user->id, //or auth()->user()->id
          'read_at' => now()
          ]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement your logic while you update the view, not while fetching the count. You could follow this approach.

```
$cookieName = "post_".$postId; // using postId to determine each post

//check if the cookie exists
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookieName])) {

   //increase view count on post table of `$postId`
  
  setcookie($cookieName, true, time() + (3600 * 2));
}
```

You could leave your current notifications sending logic as it is (if it is working), because, now on view count will be updated only when there is no cookie set.